# What does explicit clause mean in SOQL

Tags: soql

I was going through documentation of FeedItem where for *Status* field it mentions:

> These permissions do not apply when you retrieve feed items using SOQL. To filter out Pending Review feed items you must add an explicit clause.

Here is Screenshot.
[image]

Here is link to [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm)

I need to filter out PendingReview FeedItems using soql

```
SELECT Id FROM FeedItem WHERE Status != 'PendingReview'
```

returns error

> ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:31 field 'Status' can not be filtered in a query call

Answer (score 1):

The FeedItem status field doesn't support the filter option.
[image: FeedItem Status Field Properties]

You can use the following code as a workaround:

```
List<FeedItem> feedItems = new List<FeedItem>();
for(FeedItem fi : [SELECT Id, Status FROM FeedItem]) {
if(fi.Status.contains('PendingReview')) { // Any status
    feedItems.add(fi);
    }
}
System.debug(feedItems);
```